# Haskell - class constraints in typeclass definitions

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I'm fooling with an example from Learn You a Haskell and I'm not sure what's going wrong. Here's the original example, which mimics truthy/falsey semantics:

```
class YesNo a where
    yesno :: a -> Bool
```

A straightforward instance is given by:

```
instance YesNo Int where
    yesno 0 = False
    yesno _ = True
```

And then later:

```
instance YesNo (Maybe a) where
    yesno (Just _) = True
    yesno Nothing = False
```

This makes a certain amount of sense, but I find the notion that `yesno (Just False) == True` to be a little counterintuitive, and so I tried to modify it like so:

```
instance YesNo (Maybe a) where
    yesno (Just b) = yesno b
    yesno Nothing = False
```

So that in the case where the Maybe instance contains a value we get the truthiness of that value itself. However, this fails with the error `No instance for (YesNo a) arising from a use of`yesno'`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell the compiler that the type `a` must have a `YesNo` instance:

```
instance YesNo a => YesNo (Maybe a) where
    yesno (Just a) = yesno a
    yesno Nothing  = False
```

Testing:

```
> yesno (Just False)
False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make an instance of `YesNo` for `Maybe a` that only works when `a` is also an instance of `YesNo`:

```
instance (YesNo a) => YesNo (Maybe a) where
    yesno (Just b) = yesno b
    yesno Nothing = False
```

The `(YesNo a) =>` says, "for every type `a`, such that `a` is an instance of `YesNo`". The entire instance declaration the reads something like, "For every type `a`, such that `a` is an instance of `YesNo`, `Maybe a` is also an instance of `YesNo` where ...

Answer (score 0):

> So that **in the case** where the Maybe instance contains a value we get...

That can't be done really well in Haskell. Type class instances shouldn't be read "I now transfer this data type from the set of non-instances to the set of instances", but rather "I now describe how to use this type as a instance of that class". There's not really a notion of *not* being an instance of a class, only of not *finding* an instance.

So if you want to decide based on the value contained in the `Maybe`, you probably should do as suggested by Cirdec and Mikhail Glushenkov: `instance YesNo a => YesNo (Maybe a)`. Of course that means e.g. `Maybe ()` will *not* be a `YesNo` instance. You either get the same behaviour for *all* types, or another, but again all-the-same behaviour for a particular set of types. But you can't get different behaviour depending on if a type is in the class.

There is actually one way to achieve that, but it's kind of frowned upon:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverlappingInstances #-}

instance YesNo (Maybe a) where
  yesno (Just _) = True
  yesno Nothing = False

newtype YesNo_ a = YesNo_ a

instance YesNo a => YesNo (Maybe (YesNo_ a)) where
  yesno (Just (YesNo_ a)) = yesno a
  yesno Nothing  = False
```

Not only is this cumbersome, it also requires the somewhat unsafe `OverlappingInstances` extension.